# Comparing two triangles in C (3, 3, 4 and 4, 3, 3 for example)

Tags: c

I need to find all possible triangles in a set of integers. I successfully got the result, but I have many duplicates, for example:

A(3, 3, 4) == B(4, 3, 3)

I don't need to find similar triangles, I need to know when they are equal.

I tried to save my triangles as structs and wanted to compare them:

```
struct triangle
{
    int a;
    int b;     // I stored all found triangles this way
    int c;
};

int getNumberOfDuplicates(struct triangle savedTriangles[], int size) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            int a,b,c,x,y,z;
            if (i != j) {
                a = savedTriangles[i].a; b = savedTriangles[i].b; c = savedTriangles[i].c;
                x = savedTriangles[j].a; y = savedTriangles[j].b; z = savedTriangles[j].c;

            if (areTheSame) {  // Here I don't know how to compare them
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
return count;
```

Is there any mathematical way to compare them? Or any programming way?

Comment: so if i get this right, you consider triangles as equal when the 3 numbers in the struct are equal in any order?

Comment: Yes! Exactly :)

Comment: @Etoile It would be less work to modify the code that creates the list of triangles so that it does not generate duplicates.

Comment: To generate without duplicates: Sort the available edge lengths. Consider all triples, rejecting those that do not satisfy the Triangle Inequality, as you must do already, and also reject any containing a length that is equal to the previous length in the sorted list if that previous length is not also in the triple.

Comment: Check the mathematical way in my answer, it may be interesting.

Comment: @Etoile The other thing to note is that the current logic counts duplicates multiple times, even if `areTheSame` is replaced with the right comparison function. Suppose for example that you had an array with 3 identical triangles `3, 3, 4`, `3, 4, 3`, `4, 3, 3`, then the code as-is now would count `6` duplicates, while the correct answer should be `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to sort the three numbers.

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
  int tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}

void bubble_sort(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
  if (a > b) swap(&a, &b);
  if (b > c) swap(&b, &c);
  if (a > b) swap(&a, &b);
}
```

At which point it should be trivial to compare if they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two modifications to your code:

1. Just compare a triangle to the followers only, you are now counting it twice, which will give you double the desired result.
2. Sort the lengths in ascending order by using `min` and `max`, then compare them.

So your code should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) { //Start from i + 1 not 0
        int a, b, c, x, y, z, a1, b1, c1, x1, y1, z1;
        a = savedTriangles[i].a; b = savedTriangles[i].b; c = savedTriangles[i].c;
        x = savedTriangles[j].a; y = savedTriangles[j].b; z = savedTriangles[j].c;
        a1 = min(a, min(b, c));
        c1 = max(a, max(b, c));
        b1 = a + b + c - a1 - c1;
        x1 = min(x, min(y, z));
        z1 = max(x, max(y, z));
        y1 = x + y + z - x1 - z1;

        if (a1 == x1 && b1 == y1 && c1 == z1)
            count++;
    }
}

int min (int a, int b)
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

int max (int a, int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

There is a mathematical way by getting their sum, product and sum of their squares without the need to sort them, any triplet will give a unique set of results regardless of their order according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756175/find-three-numbers-given-their-sum-product-and-sum-of-their-squares), so the alternative code should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
        int a, b, c, x, y, z, s1, s2, ss1, ss2, p1, p2;
        a = savedTriangles[i].a; b = savedTriangles[i].b; c = savedTriangles[i].c;
        x = savedTriangles[j].a; y = savedTriangles[j].b; z = savedTriangles[j].c;
        s1 = a + b + c;
        ss1 = a * a + b * b + c * c;
        p1 = a * b * c;
        s2 = x + y + c;
        ss2 = x * x + y * y + z * z;
        p2 = x * y * z;
        if (s1 == s2 && ss1 == ss2 && p1 == p2)
            count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The latter is a nice math trick (+1), and you could also use `ss1 = a*b + b*c + c*a` the same way (which would actually give the coefficients of the polynomial having `a, b, c` as roots). That said, the first `min/max` approach has fewer computations, and doesn't run the risk of overflow in case of large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list is complete, every triangle will be repeated for every permutation of its sides `a, b, c`. Therefore each triangle is a duplicate of one with `a <= b <= c`, so it is enough to only check those, and automatically count any triangle with `b < a` or `c < b` as a duplicate.

```
int getNumberOfDuplicates(struct triangle savedTriangles[], int size){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int a = savedTriangles[i].a,
            b = savedTriangles[i].b,
            c = savedTriangles[i].c;
        if(b < a || c < b){
            count++;
            continue;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++){
            int x = savedTriangles[j].a,
                y = savedTriangles[j].b,
                z = savedTriangles[j].c;
            if(a == x && b == y && c == z){
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```